# Error while performing kriging interpolation in QGIS 3.8.3

Tags: qgis, interpolation, kriging

I am using QGIS 3.8.3 -Zanzibar in order to perform kriging interpolation.
I get this error massage:

```
"algorithm 'Ordinary kriging' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BLOCK' : True, 'DBLOCK' : 100, 'FIELD' : 'lb_acre', 'LOG' : True, 'POINTS' : 'file:///C:/Users/%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C/Google%20Drive/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C/R&D/wo%20pistachio/yield%20map%20401016-3/4010_16_3_1.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=Lon_adj&yField=latitude&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'PREDICTION' : 'C:/AMD/rg.sdat', 'SEARCH_DIRECTION' : 0, 'SEARCH_POINTS_ALL' : 0, 'SEARCH_POINTS_MAX' : 20, 'SEARCH_POINTS_MIN' : 16, 'SEARCH_RADIUS' : 1000, 'SEARCH_RANGE' : 0, 'TARGET_USER_FITS' : 0, 'TARGET_USER_SIZE' : 1, 'TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX' : None, 'TQUALITY' : 0, 'VARIANCE' : 'C:/AMD/retg.sdat', 'VAR_MAXDIST' : -1, 'VAR_MODEL' : 'a + b * x', 'VAR_NCLASSES' : 100, 'VAR_NSKIP' : 1 }

statistics_kriging "Ordinary Kriging" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -POINTS "C:/Users/שראל/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_28777ed756654e7089095e07186c04f2/75a66ffbc5de4eada6fad02bf13dd4d6/POINTS.shp" -FIELD "lb_acre" -TQUALITY 0 -LOG true -BLOCK true -DBLOCK 100.0 -VAR_MAXDIST -1.0 -VAR_NCLASSES 100 -VAR_NSKIP 1 -VAR_MODEL "a + b * x" -TARGET_USER_SIZE 1.0 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -SEARCH_RANGE 0 -SEARCH_RADIUS 1000.0 -SEARCH_POINTS_ALL 0 -SEARCH_POINTS_MIN 16 -SEARCH_POINTS_MAX 20 -SEARCH_DIRECTION 0 -PREDICTION "C:/AMD/rg.sdat"
statistics_kriging "Ordinary Kriging" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -POINTS "C:/Users/שראל/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_28777ed756654e7089095e07186c04f2/75a66ffbc5de4eada6fad02bf13dd4d6/POINTS.shp" -FIELD "lb_acre" -TQUALITY 0 -LOG true -BLOCK true -DBLOCK 100.0 -VAR_MAXDIST -1.0 -VAR_NCLASSES 100 -VAR_NSKIP 1 -VAR_MODEL "a + b * x" -TARGET_USER_SIZE 1.0 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -SEARCH_RANGE 0 -SEARCH_RADIUS 1000.0 -SEARCH_POINTS_ALL 0 -SEARCH_POINTS_MIN 16 -SEARCH_POINTS_MAX 20 -SEARCH_DIRECTION 0 -PREDICTION "C:/AMD/rg.sdat" -VARIANCE "C:/AMD/retg.sdat"

Execution completed in 6.57 seconds
Results:
{'PREDICTION': 'C:/AMD/rg.sdat', 'VARIANCE': 'C:/AMD/retg.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
**The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/AMD/retg.sdat</li><li>C:/AMD/rg.sdat</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm."
```

I would be gratefull for solution.

Comment: Are `C:/AMD/rg.sdat` and `C:/AMD/retg.sdat` files there? Do they have a size (more than zero bytes)?